# Find the x-coordinate of the point of intersection.

Tags: geometry

I saw a diagram of two perpendicular semicircles in The Elements and put two axes through them to make a problem. What is the x-coordinate of the point of intersection of the tangent and the semicircle?

Sorry for the poor diagram:

[image]

Could you find the most elegant solution?

Comment: Fun fact the answer can be written in terms of the Golden Ratio: $$a=\frac{1}{1-2\varphi}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the diagram below:-
[image]

It is not that difficult to see that:-

(1) The two tangents are equal in length (and = 2)

(2) By properties of tangents, $\angle KHO = \angle PHO = x$)

(3) $H$, $K$, $O$, $P$ are con-cyclic.

(4) By ext. angle cyclic quadrilateral, $\angle POA = 2x$

(5) $HO = \sqrt{5}$

(6) $\cos x = \frac{2} {\sqrt{5}}$ and $\sin x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$

$a = \frac{a}{1} = \cos 2x$

$= cos^2x – sin^2 x$

$= \left(\frac {2} {\sqrt 5}\right)^2 – \left(\frac {1}{\sqrt 5}\right)^2$

$= \frac {3}{5}$

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure the solution is 0.6. I solved it putting the equation for the upper tangent and the derivative of the semicircle's equation and solving.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

You know that your tanget stars in $(-1|2)$ due to the fact that you consider unit circles and it passes through a point on the circle $P=(a|y)$, where $y=\sqrt{1-a^2}$.

Hence the tangent equation is $t(x)=\frac{y-2}{a+1}x + 2a+y$. You want $t(a)=\sqrt{1-a^2}$, which leads to the equation

$$t(a)=\frac{\sqrt{1-a^2}-2}{a+1}\cdot a + 2a +\sqrt{1-a^2}=\sqrt{1-a^2}$$

The only real solution for this is $a\approx 0.3884$.